# All vertical oriented images are strangely autorotated only on some devices

Tags: android, android-image, android-bitmap, android-image-capture

I have an app that take pictures from camera or gallery and shows the result in an imageview.

I only get the image with content provider and use this scale function

```
public Bitmap scaleim(Bitmap bitmap) {
       ...
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, resizedWidth, resizedHeight, false);
        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```

In my devices with android 5 everything works ok, now I have tested the same App on a my friend device with Android 7, and **every pictures that is vertical oriented is automatically rotated to horizontal orientation**. 
This looks really weird and I have no idea of what causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in scaling but captured images work differently as per the hardware.Before start scaling that should be rotated as per suitable devices.
Here it is following code:

```
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(url));
  Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
  bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true)

public static int getImageOrientation(String imagePath){
     int rotate = 0;
     try {

         File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
         ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                 imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
         int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                 ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                 ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

         switch (orientation) {
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
             rotate = 270;
             break;
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
             rotate = 180;
             break;
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
             rotate = 90;
             break;
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return rotate;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot find a valid way to get the file path from uri with this method and returns me FileNotFoundException. Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: I believe it should have path before it turned to a bitmap. scaleim(Bitmap bitmap)